# Flatten 2D texture in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, flatten

Lets say I have a 2D texture with a single depth component. What would be the fastest method of flattening such an image into a 1D texture, also with a depth component, using the built-in Depth Test, such that the final output texture contains all the lowest depth values for every column of the input texture?

The obvious way that comes to mind is to write a fragment shader that combines each column manually:

```
//Intended as Pseudocode, not actually tested.

//The input texture and it's height
uniform sampler2D input_texture;
uniform float input_height;

//The fragments position in clip space
varying vec2 position;

void main() {
    float depth = 1.0;
    for (float y = 0.0; y < input_height; y += 1.0) {
        float sample = texture2D(input_texture, vec2(position.x, y/input_height)).x;
        depth = min(depth, sample);
    }
    gl_FragDepth = depth;
}
```

But that wouldn't take complete advantage of parallelism on the GPU.

A similar technique would be to generate a fragment for every pixel in the 2d texture, but that ignores the y coordinate, or something along those lines, but I'm pretty sure that would be impossible, since we don't have complete control over fragment generation.

Just a note, for compatibility purposes, I need to restrict this to OpenGL 3.0 or less. I know there are probably nicer methods for 4.0+, but those aren't viable in my case.

Comment: You could try drawing input_height number of quads that are one pixel high on top of each other and assigning different texture coordinates for each one based on the current column you are drawing. That way you could get rid of the loop in your shader and just do the texture lookup and set the frag depth and let the hardware depth testing handle the rest.

Comment: That would definitely work, but it sounds like a similarly hacky workaround to something like this. It would also be a pretty big pain to create something like ~2000-4000 different quads *just* to flatten an image.

Comment: You don't need to use quads for that, (non-multisampled) points will work fine.